# Can QGIS2Web turn some layers off when loading so that they do not initially appear on the map, but do appear in the menu

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis2web

I have created a map using QGIS2Web (OpenLayers option). Is there a setting to turn some layers off when creating the map such that it opens with some layers not showing, but contains the layer names in the map menu so the layers can be turned on later.

Answer (score 2):

I see now...
Open QGIS2Web --> Layers and Groups
Select a layer you want visible later. Open the options for that layer and deselect the "Visible" option.

Answer (score 1):

**You can also use for layers
rendering - "Scale Dependent Visibility" within QGIS.**
It works for qgis2web.
If you use this function for example for layer "one", the "visible" function within qgis2web should be checked.
I think for leaflet it is a little bit better as for openlayers, because:
If you are zoom and the layer is hidden, the checkbox within the layer map legend in leaflet is unchecked (correct), but checked in openlayers (maybe an issue...)

It is for some projects or for some layers an alternative to the "visible" option within qgis2web.